# MySQL login after secure installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, installation, logins

I have installed `mysql5.5` via secure installation procedure by using:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Now when I am trying to login in MySQL from the terminal by using:

```
sudo -u root -p
```

The following error is displayed:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have also used:

```
sudo -u root
```

Which I got the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What should I do for this error?

Comment: Does your MySQL password contain any special characters? Maybe the mysql_secure_installation command can't cope with them. try with a password with no special charcter

Comment: @Mehdi : No, My MySQL password is not contain any spescial characters.Password is a simple.

Comment: One option that you can make easily , its remove your current version of mysql ... and reinstall but this time remember your user and passwd

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a `.my.cnf` file in your home directory, which is specifying a password.

The clue here is that when you did not specify a password (`sudo -u root`), the error message is still saying that you did.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your root password:

1) run this: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

2) from a separated ssh terminal: `sudo mysql --user=root mysql`

3) run this query: `update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';`

4) and then run this query: `flush privileges;`

5) restart mysqld service.

and then try to connect again using new password in first query.

Comment: When i run step no.:3 ,i got error like " -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ".What should i do for this?

Comment: you have to run this query in mysql environment, not in bash command line! this is a mysql query! after step 2, you will enter into mysql environment, so paste step 3 in that.

Comment: But i can't able to login in MySQL environment.After step 2 i can't able to enter into MySQL environment.

Comment: did you run first command in another console?

Comment: No, all command i run in one console.is it correct?

Comment: no , fist command is in another console

Comment: I have run first command is in another console But i got following error : ` /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 126: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied `

Comment: run with sudo: sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Comment: I run first command in one console.I got in output :` 131216 11:12:59 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists ` Is it right?

Comment: yes, on other console run from step 2 and go on

Comment: When i run step no:2 command then i got error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.